# Verify and Assert functions does not work as expected in Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, java, xpath, selenium-ide, angular

I'm using Selenium IDE to record steps. Web system has developed using Angular.js
I tried to use verify text and assert text functions through IDE. For target elements, xpath is given. Same xpath is used to fill data into the field. But when try to assert or verify, the element is not recognized. How should I fix this?

[image: Selenium IDE image]

Comment: You mention `The element is not recognized`. Are you seeing some error indicating there is no such element? Or is the error you get that `dane` was not found as the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some html like this:

```
<div id="someID">some text</div>
```

Then calling `verify text` with `Value == some text` for `xpath=//div[@id='someID']` will confirm that the text is `some text`

If you are filling out an input, usually the html DOES NOT immediately or ever(unless there is some script to update the html) look like this:

```
<input id="someID">the text you just typed</input>
```

Rather it just looks like this:

```
<input id="someID"></input> //notice no text in there <<<
```

So what do you do instead?

You can check the html to see if that value is stored somewhere on the element as an attribute or somewhere else to verify against...

But more likely for a meaningful test, you just want to submit that text, and verify that value ends up where it's supposed to after you submit it.

Comment: I dont have the html like that since the project is in angular. But I think the problem is  with the input as you mentioned. "If you are filling out an input, usually the html DOES NOT immediately or ever(unless there is some script to update the html) look like this:" This is the problem  here.  So I will accept the answer